# How to create function in my AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS. I want to create cart shopping to WebSQL. How to create function addToCart and removeCart?.

Here is my code :

```
angular.module('ecommerce').factory('CartService',
    ['$webSql', '$http', '$q', 'urls',
        function ($webSql, $http, $q, urls) {

            var factory = {
                addToCart: addToCart,
                removeCart: removeCart
            };

            return factory;]
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Function can be created in different ways .So in your case :

Solution 1 : Function Expression

```
angular.module('ecommerce').factory('CartService',
['$webSql', '$http', '$q', 'urls',
    function ($webSql, $http, $q, urls) {
        var addToCart = function () {//body of function}
        var factory = {
            addToCart: addToCart,
            removeCart: removeCart
        };

        return factory;]
    }
]);
```

Solution 2 : Function Declaration

```
angular.module('ecommerce').factory('CartService',
['$webSql', '$http', '$q', 'urls',
    function ($webSql, $http, $q, urls) {
        function addTocart () {//Body of function}
        var factory = {
            addToCart: addToCart,
            removeCart: removeCart
        };

        return factory;]
    }
]);
```

A function expression looks similar to function declarations, except that the function is assigned to a variable name.

Comment: So I want to create an addToCart function using a query for WeSQL. But I'm still confused how to make the query. Can you hel me sir?

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('ecommerce').factory('CartService',
['$webSql', '$http', '$q', 'urls',
    function ($webSql, $http, $q, urls) {
        function addTocart () {
        $http.get(yoururl).then(response){
        console.log(response.data)
        }
        }
        var factory = {
            addToCart: addToCart,
            removeCart: removeCart
        };

    return factory;]
}
]);
```